# How to show names in Jtextfield click on JButton using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am fresher in **Netbeans**. I have a small assignment related **Netbeans**. I want to show some names in **JTextfield**(for example "abcd","ijkl","mnop" etc as next by next) and it must show  *one by one*. I had create some code which not working properly. I am looking some helps related to it. Please mention as full code here that I can understand in future.I do not know how to create it. So i am done it some another ways. But showing error message.  My code is as follows.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String s[]={"abcd","ijkl","mnop" } ;


 for(int d=0; d<s.length;d++)



  jTextField1.setText(""+s);

}
```

Comment: what error message is showing?

Comment: _it must show one by one_. means what

Comment: @Satya it means when click on Jbutton the 1st name (Example "abcd") must show. then Jbutton click  show 2nd name (Example "efgh")  then show 3rd name when click on Jbutton.

Comment: @RobertLongson  the error message is "[Ljava.lang.String;@478b934c"

Comment: Its not error message. its a address since you are printing string array obj.

Comment: so for each and every click you want to display a string from string array.

Comment: @Satya how i can solve the problem?

Comment: @Satya yes  I am thinking like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these variables should be inside of your class but outside of any method.

```
String s[]={"abcd","ijkl","mnop" } ;
int i=0;
```

In action performed method

```
if(i>=s.length)
   i=0;

jTextField1.setText(s[i]);
i++;
```

For the first click, display `abcd`.

Next click, display `ijkl`.

Next click, display `mnop`.

But I didn't check it. Just try it. It will works.

Comment: In this code it is showing all in single click.
I told you that I need it is one by one .

for example 1. abcd when button click in jtextfield will show next name that is 2. ijkl then button click next name that is mnop.

Comment: Why are you thinking like that is it your requirement